# How many pixels are in a PDF point?

Tags: pdf

I am tasked with mapping points on a PDF form to an XML output. How many pixels represent a point in a PDF form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3455016/1699210

Comment: A default user space unit in pdf by default is 1/72 inch. How large is your pixel? (Often it's 1/96 inch, is it in your case?)