# what unit is pdf resolution in and does DPI affect it

Tags: pdf

When inspecting a PDF file, a 'resolution' can be seen:

[image: PDF file info showing 'Resolution']

In this example the 'Resolution' is 595x841. There is no 'DPI' shown in the above file dialog, however when exporting as PDF it is possible to set the DPI. Regardless of what DPI setting is chosen, the 'Resolution' is always the same.

For A6 'resolution' is 297x419, about half in each dimension.

What unit is resolution measure in, and is it linked directly to the size only, or does the DPI affect it (and I just haven't been setting it correctly?)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not clear, but PDF dimensions (referred to as 'Resolution' by mac file info dialog) are in 'user units' [which then correlate to](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-userunit-pdf-file) 'points'. Prior to PDF version 1.6, its a 1:1 relationship.

*Since PDF version 1.6:* There is a setting `/UserUnit` which is usually `1`, and `user_points x /UserUnit = points`.

A 'user unit' is ALWAYS [1/72 of an inch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455016/how-are-pdf-sizes-specified?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). So 0.35277777777777775mm per point. (Though you *can* scale a PDF to fit different sized pages in most print dialogs)

PDFs do NOT themselves have a DPI. PDFs contain things, some of which MAY have the equivalent - text and *vector* images are scalable and do not, whereas with *raster* images each one has a 'ppi' ([point per inch](https://superuser.com/a/1135528/136696)).

When creating a PDF, you may use a raster image with a very high resolution, but PDFs do 'filtering' on raster images to reduce their resolution so the 'ppi' is similar to the 'DPI' of the page (usually chosen on export of PDF). This means that the smaller you make an image on the page, the lower the resolution it will need to have to have the desired 'ppi'. Thus filtering compresses raster images to stop the PDF being unnecessarily large (filesize) by having lots of unneeded detail.

So in the file dialog, 'Resolution' is always in 'user points', multiply it by /UserPoint to get 'points', and that divided by 72 and is the intended physical size in inches. You can of course print an A4 PDF at A2 size; it just means the embedded raster images will each have half their 'ppi' available to the printer.

Comment: IMO the appropriate answer should be that "resolution" simply does not make sense in the context of a PDF and is a misnomer here. Each PDF page has dimensions, in the case of the question probably 595pt x 841pt, but that's not a resolution.

Comment: ah... if I change 'resolution' to read 'dimension', is everything else correct? The dimensions are 'pt' and they are 1/72 of an inch?

Comment: I don't want to be nitpicking, but the measurement unit in PDF's isn't the point, but the *user unit*. By default, 1 inch corresponds with 72 user units, which corresponds with 72 points. Hence you could say that 1 user unit equals 1 point *by default*. However, there is a `/UserUnit` property that can change the default. If this property is used and different from 1, your claim that the measurement unit corresponds with the typographical point is no longer correct. However, there are very few PDF's that define a `/UserUnit` that is different from the default.

Comment: @Bruno You *are* nitpicking... but correctly so. ;) Yes, the default value (i.e. if **UserUnit** is absent) for the default user space unit (here: "default" = before any transformations are applied) is 1/72 inch which coincides with the definition of one of the "point" units.

Comment: Nitpicking is very much appreciated! Hoping to build a perfect understanding of PDF page dimensions structure. The guides I read do not mention it. So should an A4 PDF have dimensions (what mac file info calls 'Resolution') of 595x841, or would it be fine to send to a printer a PDF with dimensions 5950x8410 and thus a /UserUnit of 0.1?

Comment: It depends on which specification you are reading. If you read Adobe's PDF specification for PDF 1.7, you read that Acrobat 7.0 supports a *maximum* UserUnit value of 75,000. The *minimum* UserUnit value is 1.0. Hence a UserUnit of 0.1 is impossible. Starting with ISO 32000-1, the specification says that the range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent. In theory, it could be 0.1 based on ISO 32000-1 (as well as on ISO 32000-2), but I don't think many implementations support a UserUnit value lower than 1.

Comment: As far as I remember some PDF processors (e.g. Adobe's Reader) only consider(ed?) **UserUnit** values greater than 1 valid. So the other way around would give rise to a nice example, i.e. a **UserUnit** value of 10 and a **CropBox** size of 59.5 times 84.1 default user space units should result in an A4 page.By the way, A4 permits a small deviation from the exact specified dimensions, so you may find A4 pages with slightly different numbers. Ah, @Bruno was a bit faster here... ;)

Comment: I always use 595 x 842 for pages in the A4 format. Hence when you create a document with iText, A4 pages will have a size of 595 x 842. I think Adobe uses the same values for A4 pages.